# FInd all lists of 4 positive integers whose sum is 100

Tags: algorithm, sum, dart, combinations

I'd like to generate a list of all possible lists of 4 positive integers whose sum equals 100, exactly. (The summands do not need to be unique.)

Possible example snippet:

```
[
 // Using (1+1+1+97)
 [1,1,1,97],
 [1,1,97,1],
 [1,97,1,1],
 [97,1,1,1],

 // Using (2+1+1+96)
 [2,1,1,96],
 [2,1,96,1],
 [2,96,1,1],
 [96,2,1,1],

 [1,2,1,96],
 [1,2,96,1],
 [1,96,2,1],
 [96,1,2,1],

 [1,1,2,96],
 [1,1,96,2],
 [1,96,1,2],
 [96,1,1,2],

 // Using (2+2+1+95), etc...
]
```

What's an efficient way of doing this? (Pseudo-code or advice is fine.)

Comment: What have you attempted so far?

Comment: I added it to the question text just now

Comment: `// N is 4, ingredients.length is 100` but then : `var start = N - ingredients.length; // 97` ???

Comment: Ok, so now it is `-95`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a generic solution for any number of parts:

```dart
// create(100, 4) returns the 156849 solutions
Iterable<List<int>> create(int max, int parts) sync* {
  assert(max >= parts);
  if (parts == 1) {
    yield [max];
  } else {
    for (int i = max - parts + 1; i > 0; i--) {
      yield* create(max - i, parts - 1).map((e) => e.toList()..add(i));
    }
  }
}
```

And a more optimized solution for 4 numbers:

```dart
// create(100) returns the 156849 solutions
Iterable<List<int>> create(int max) sync* {
  for (int a = 1; a <= max - 3; a++) { // -3 because b/c/d are >= 1
    for (int b = 1; b <= max - a; b++) {
      for (int c = 1; c <= max - a - b - 1; c++) { // -1 because d is >=1
        yield [a, b, c, max - a - b - c];
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I like the use of sync* and yield :)

Comment: Impressive, love it!

Answer (score 2):

I think it is best to start with a solution and then change the solution to other valid solutions. I assume 0 is not a valid number.

Lets start at [97,1,1,1] 
then we substract one from 97, leaving 96.
we have [96,1,1,1] leaving 1. So we have a question that gives us the partial answer:

"generate a list of all possible lists of 3 positive integers whose sum equals 4"

then we substract one from 96,

"generate a list of all possible lists of 3 positive integers whose sum equals 5"

then we substract one from 95,

"generate a list of all possible lists of 3 positive integers whose sum equals 6"

etc. etc.

because the bunch of questions  really looks much like the original question we can re-do the trick to go from 3 places to 2 places.
[2,1,1] (leaving 1) => "generate a list of all possible lists of 2 positive integers whose sum equals 3" which is easy to write.

Now you can simply write a nice recursive formula.

Answer (score 2):

Iterative and recursive solutions:
(Try it on [DartPad](https://dartpad.dartlang.org/f8c7f799ca4884741d70)

```
void main() {
  List<List<int>> resultList1 = <List<int>>[];
    for(int i1 = 1; i1 < 98; i1++)  {
    for(int i2 = 1; (i1 + i2) < 99; i2++) {
      for(int i3 = 1; (i1 + i2 + i3) < 100; i3++) {
        for(int i4 = 1; (i1 + i2 + i3 + i4) <= 100; i4++) {
          if((i1 + i2 + i3 +i4) == 100) {
            resultList1.add([i1, i2, i3, i4]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
//  print(resultList1);
  print(resultList1.length);
  final int elementCount = 4;
  final int target = 100;
  final List<List<int>> resultList2 = <List<int>>[];
  sum(elementCount, target, resultList2, [0, 0, 0, 0], 0);
//  print(result);
  print(resultList2.length);
}

void sum(int elementCount, int target, List<List<int>> result, List<int> values,
    int curPos) {
  for (int i = values[curPos] + 1; i <= target - curPos; i++) {
    // debugging only
//    if(curPos == 0) {
//      print(i);
//    }
    // end debugging only
    values[curPos] = i;
    if (curPos == elementCount - 1) {
      if (values.reduce((int a, int b) => a + b) == 100) {
//        print(values);
        result.add(values.toList());
      }
    } else {
      sum(elementCount, target, result, values, curPos + 1);
    }

    for(int j = curPos + 1; j < values.length; j++) {
      values[j] = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

The result contains 156849 elements from `[1,1,1,97]` to `[97,1,1,1]`.
The recursive version supports variable number of elements and variable sum target value. For example by calling it like:

```
  final int elementCount = 3;
  final int target = 50;
  final List<List<int>> resultList2 = <List<int>>[];
  sum(elementCount, target, resultList2, [0, 0, 0], 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the most straightforward way is to use 3 loops.

```
resultList = []
for a from 1 to 97:
  for b from 1 to 97:
    for c from 1 to 97:
      d = 100-a-b-c
      if d > 0:
        resultList.append([a,b,c,d])
```

Comment: Agreed, but what if there were many  more than 4 summands (say, 30 numbers who add up to 100?)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath If recursion is appropriate for this, could you please post that as answer with a bit more elaboration?

Answer (score 1):

recursive approach:

```
MakeSum(Sum, NItems, ResultList)
  if NItems = 1
    output ResultList + [Sum]
  else
     for i = 1 to Sum - NItems + 1
        MakeSum(Sum - i, NItems - 1, ResultList + [i])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution in Python that produces all possible results in lexicographic order:

```
resultList = []
for a in xrange(1,98):
    for b in xrange(1,98):
        for c in xrange(1,98):
            d = 100 - a - b - c
            if d > 0 and a <= b <= c <= d:
                resultList.append([a,b,c,d])
```

The result list has 7153 entries, beginning with [1,1,1,97] and ending with [25,25,25,25]. You can run the program at http://ideone.com/8m7b1h.

Comment: Great, thanks! Dart: https://dartpad.dartlang.org/40d3607a2d122a6606d6. A recursive solution would be ideal since 3 nested loops doesn't scale and depends on there being _exactly_ 4 numbers which must add to 100. If it changed to 5 numbers or 6, etc... the code would break or need refactoring.

Comment: @Ganymede: My solution produces 7153 results because it removes duplicates that differ only in the order of their entries. Some other solutions produce 156849 results including duplicates. What is the desired behavior?

Comment: I wanted all permutations (e.g. [1,1,1,97] is not a duplicate of [1,1,97,1] and I want both). I admit I didn't say that clearly in the question, but the examples I included show that is the behavior I seek.